# Generic Interface type conversion issues

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have been battling with this bit of code for a while now and I am trying to get a solution as it is literally the last part before it goes to testing.

I have the following interfaces and classes (simplified to the relevant parts):

```
public interface ITagParent<T> where T : ITag
{
    List<TagAddOn<T>> TagCollection { get; set; }
}

public interface ITag
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    TagGroup TagGroup { get; set; }
}

public class TagAddOn<T> : ViewModelBase where T : ITag
{
    private T _currentTag;
    public T CurrentTag
    {
        get { return _currentTag; }
        set { _currentTag = value; }
    }
}

public partial class Customer : ITagParent<CustomerTag>
{
    List<TagAddOn<CustomerTag>> _tagCollection;
    public List<TagAddOn<CustomerTag>> TagCollection
    {
        get { return _tagCollection; }
        set { _tagCollection = value; }
    }
}

public partial class CustomerTag : ITag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class TagAddOnManager
{
    public static string GetTagCurrentValue(List<TagAddOn<ITag>> dataObjectAddOns)
    {
        // LOTS OF SNIPPING!
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the `GetTagCurrentValue` method in the `TagAddOnManager` class like this:

```
string value = TagAddOnManager.GetTagCurrentValue(
    ((ITagParent<ITag>)gridCell.Row.Data).TagCollection));
```

Everything compiles fine, but errors when trying to cast `gridCell.Row.Data` to `ITagParent<ITag>`. I understand this is due to covarience and a workaround (if not a terribly safe one) is to mark `T` in the `ITagParent` interface with the `out` keyword, but that won't work as you can see it is used in the `TagCollection` property, which can't be read only.

I tried casting the above to `ITagParent<CustomerTag>`, but this fails at compile time with a 'cannot convert' error when trying to feed it into my `GetTagCurrentValue` method.

Another option I considered is using some base classes instead of the `ITagParent` interface, but that won't work as the `Customer` object already inherits from another base class, which can't be modified for this implementation.

I know I could just overload the `GetTagCurrentValue` method with `List<TagAddOn<CustomerTag>>` as the parameter type and all other variations, but that really seems like a 'I give up' solution. I could probably use reflection to get the desired results, but that would be unwieldy and not very efficient, especially considering this method could be called a lot in a particular process.

So does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use something like that

```
public class TagAddOnManager
{
    public static string GetTagCurrentValue<TTag>(ITagParent<TTag> tagParent)
        where TTag : ITag
    {
        // Just an example.
        return tagParent.TagCollection.First().CurrentTag.Description;
    }
}
```

and use it like that?`

```
var value = TagAddOnManager.GetTagCurrentValue((Customer)CustomergridCell.Row.Data);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a more generic version in the usage part of it (i.e. no casting to the `Customer` object), but for the time being this is pretty good as the rest is generic.